# Overlapping double arrows in drop down menu

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

The arrows in the drop down menu have two sets of arrows and they overlap each other (picture in the link below). This is in a ruby on rails app.

The arrows disappear when the drop down menu is enabled.

[A drop down menu with two sets of drop down arrows overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYFV0.png)

```
display: block;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
color: #212121;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding to the element.

```
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
```